# Cannot find module 'crypto'

Tags: node.js, authentication, meteor, npm

I am trying implementing [duo](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs) but when I try to use it I got this error:

```
import Duo from 'duo_web';
```

I installed it `meteor npm install duo_web --save`, on *windows 10*, `node v8.9.0`, `npm v5.5.1`. I know [duo_nodejs](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_nodejs) uses `crypto` module and its also installed.

*package.json*

```
"crypto": "^1.0.1",
"duo_web": "^1.0.2",
```

Comment: `crypto` is builtin package. You don't need to install it.

Comment: I know that just I tried to make it work but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `crypto` is a Node package, you need to supply it on the browser side. In Meteor this is most easily done using

```
meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs
```

Which will bring in the Node specific packages that your project and dependencies use.

These can be quite large, so it's worth keeping an eye on bundle size.

ADDED: Although, looking at `duo_web`, they have a browser version without crypto at `duo_web/js/Duo-Web-v2.js`, so it looks like the best solution is to use:

```
import Duo from 'duo_web';
```

In your server code and:

```
import Duo from 'duo_web/js/Duo-Web-v2';
```

In your client code. 
Then you won't need crypto on the client and your bundle will be much smaller as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, except for client side its `v1` so It should be `import Duo from 'duo_web/js/Duo-Web-v1';`